# Python & Pandas: match and transpose

Tags: python, pandas

The original table is like:

```
ID Name Sex Weight Date
1  Bill M   68.1   2015-01-01
2  Mary F   45.2   2015-01-01
3  Gary M   89.2   2015-01-01
1  Bill M   68.3   2015-01-02
2  Mary F   45.3   2015-01-02
3  Gary M   89.1   2015-01-02
```

---

The desired output is:

```
ID Name Sex 2015-01-01 2015-01-02
1  Bill M   68.1   68.3
2  Mary F   45.2   45.3
3  Gary M   89.2   89.1
```

---

Is there any quick way to get the desired data frame?
I tried to create a new data frame and append row by row by using ret.loc[i] = row_list, but it's too slow when the data set gets big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print df.pivot_table(index=['ID', 'Name','Sex'], columns='Date', values='Weight')
Date         2015-01-01  2015-01-02
ID Name Sex                        
1  Bill M          68.1        68.3
2  Mary F          45.2        45.3
3  Gary M          89.2        89.1
```

And if you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['ID', 'Name','Sex'], columns='Date', values='Weight')
df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#if you need sorting columns
df= df.sort_index(axis = 1)
df = df.reset_index()

print df
   ID  Name Sex  2015-01-01  2015-01-02
0   1  Bill   M        68.1        68.3
1   2  Mary   F        45.2        45.3
2   3  Gary   M        89.2        89.1
```

Or:

```
print df.pivot_table(index=['ID', 'Name','Sex'], columns='Date', values='Weight').reset_index()
Date  ID  Name Sex  2015-01-01 00:00:00  2015-01-02 00:00:00
0      1  Bill   M                 68.1                 68.3
1      2  Mary   F                 45.2                 45.3
2      3  Gary   M                 89.2                 89.1
```

Comment: thanks a lot! one more question: luckly the dates are sorted, but the question is how i can make use it is sorted.

Comment: Maybe you can use [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with `axis=1`

Comment: Or if you need sort  column `Date` - [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) - `df.sort_values('Date')`

Comment: so first i use table = df.pivot_table(index=['ID', 'Name','Sex'], columns='Date', values='Weight').reset_index() and then table = table.sort_index(axis = 1). Now ID Name and Sex are the last three columns, but I want them to be the first three columns

Comment: Answer is edited - you need sorting before reseting index, but I think `pivot_table` sort column names.

Comment: That's really helpful! Thanks!